# About determinations of the log in SE(3) (or SE(n))

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm interested in the special Euclidean group, especially in the case $n=3$.
We know $\exp \colon se(3) \rightarrow SE(3)$ is surjective but not injective, however $\exp$ is a local diffeomorphism between a nbhd of $0 \in se(3)$ to a nhbd of $e \in SE(3)$.

Is it possible to explicitly write the $\log$ part of the diffeomorphism then transport it around any point of $SE(3)$ by left or right translation ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean, is it possible to compose the exponential map with left multiplication by fixed $g$ to obtain a local diffeomorphism between a neighbourhood of $0\in\mathfrak{g}$ and a neighbourhood of $g\in G$, then yes. This is simply the map $X\mapsto g\exp(X)$ (restricted to the neighbourhood). It is the composition of diffeomorphisms so is a diffeomorphism. Its inverse would be $h \mapsto \log(g^{-1}h)$.

Comment: Cheers mate, I should have thought about it